# Python use ffmpeg not running when using os.system

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, os.system, pydub

I have been trying to convert mp3 audio to wav file using subprocess. I have installed ffmpeg and libav using home-brew. However whenever I run my code.

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp3',
               'output.wav'])
```

I get this error

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg': 'ffmpeg'

1. I have tried to use pydub but always get ffprobe errors
2. I have tried
       using os.system alternatively

For reference I am using macOS Mojave, python 3.7

Edit:

Instead of using ['ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp3', 'output.wav']

Use ['path/to/ffmpeg', '-i', 'input.mp3', 'output.wav']

Ways to find the path to ffmpeg-----------------------

Unix(Linux, Mac): find ffmpeg

Windows: Where ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the whole path to the ffmpeg executable rather than just`ffmpeg`

Comment: Where would the path be located

Comment: You should be able to run `where ffmpeg` in your command line to get the path. For me it's `C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe`.

Comment: Thanks I have tried what you have said and it no longer displays an error however the  conversion still hasn't occurred.